# Is there a way to enforce a schema constraint on an AWS DynamoDB table?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm a MSSQL developer who recently was tasked with building a new application using DynamoDB since we use AWS and we wanted a highly scaleable database service.

My biggest concern is data integrity. For example, I have a table for all my users where every row needs to have a username, email, and name field, all strings, with a verified field that's an int. Is there anyway to require all entries in that table to have those fields and to be of that particular type?

Since the application is in PHP I'm using [Kettle](https://github.com/inouet/kettle) as my ORM which should prevent me from messing up the data integrity but another developer voiced a concern about if we ever add another application or if someone manually changes some types via the console.
https://github.com/inouet/kettle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, no, you are responsible for maintaining the integrity of your items with respect to the existence of attributes that are not keys on the base table. However, you can use LSI and GSI to enforce data types of attributes (notwithstanding my qualm that this is not a recommended pattern, as it could cause partition heat especially for attributes whose range of values is small). For example, verified seems like it might take only 0 or 1 as a value, so if you create a GSI with PK=verified where verified is a Number, writes to the base table may get throttled by the verified GSI.