# Enforce Schema validation in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Is it possible to enforce table level schema validation on DynamoDB

For instance, consider the following table

```
aws dynamodb create-table\
      --table-name spaces-tabs-votes\
      --attribute-definitions AttributeName=id,AttributeType=S
      --key-schema AttributeName=id,KeyType=HASH
      --provisioned-throughput ReadCapacityUnits=1,WriteCapacityUnits=1
      --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

At time T, table looked like below (Notice that `votes` is of type `N`)

```
$ aws dynamodb scan --table-name spaces-tabs-votes
{
    "Count": 2,
    "Items": [
        {
            "votes": {
                "N": "104"
            },
            "id": {
                "S": "space"
            }
        },
        {
            "votes": {
                "N": "60"
            },
            "id": {
                "S": "tab"
            }
        }
    ],
    "ScannedCount": 2,
    "ConsumedCapacity": null
}
```

At time T+1, I was able to change the type of `votes` from `N` to `S`. All I had to do was do a `put` with `votes` set as String `1` instead of incrementing the already existing `N` value.

```
$ aws dynamodb scan --table-name spaces-tabs-votes
{
    "Count": 2,
    "Items": [
        {
            "votes": {
                "N": "104"
            },
            "id": {
                "S": "space"
            }
        },
        {
            "votes": {
                "S": "1"
            },
            "id": {
                "S": "tab"
            }
        }
    ],
    "ScannedCount": 2,
    "ConsumedCapacity": null
}
```

I would like schema enforcement - i.e, if the record that I am trying to post to DynamoDB doesn't conform to a schema, I want it to throw an exception. Is it possible at all?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to enforce a schema constraint on an AWS DynamoDB table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42563529/is-there-a-way-to-enforce-a-schema-constraint-on-an-aws-dynamodb-table)